# Keep a view through activities

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a Webview with a bunch of Javascript inside, that needs a couple of seconds for the inital loading.

Since I do not want the user to experience this loading time more than once, I want to keep this view, while switching between activities.

Is there a way to keep a view alive while switching activities, or could I save the initialized view to a file to pass it as extra to the next activity?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is there a way to keep a view alive while switching activities

The `WebView` will remain a part of the original activity until such time as that activity is destroyed.

> or could I save the initialized view to a file to pass it as extra to the next activity?

No.

However, you are welcome to get rid of the multiple activities, or otherwise reorganize your UI to only need the `WebView` in one activity.